# Discord bot logged successfully but not working command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

Brief description of problem:

I made my first discord bot by checking the official discord bot docs, it goes online and all good but when i put the command it doesn't work.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.once("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {

  if (interaction.command === "ping") {
    console.log("pong");
  }
});

client.login("My Token");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, verify that the interaction is a slash command using the `isChatInputCommand` function, because there are many other types of interactions in Discord now.

Second, the property of `interaction` with the slash command's name is `commandName`. Example:

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    
    if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
        console.log("pong");
    }
})
```

Comment: i tried this code:

```
client.once("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
    if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
      console.log("pong");
    }
  }
});
```
Is that what u ment?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Make sure you're actually logging something in that `console.log` tho

Comment: yes i'm logging correctly, the message displays as it need to do, but still doesn't works

Comment: So it logs "pong"? Then what are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: No that's the thing it doesn't log "pong" the only log i get is: "Logged in as PingPong#4179!"

Comment: Have you actually created your slash command yet through the @discord.js/rest library? If so, when you run the command on Discord, what happens? Does it just say "The application did not respond"?

Comment: Actually I didn't seen that in the tutorial, but where do i create it in the index.js file?

Comment: Then your problem isn't with the event listener, it's with registering your commands. [Here's the discord.js guide on registering and responding to slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html)

Comment: Cheers man, i didn't knew about that thanks for helping me!